# Flash not working in mediaelement.js HTML5 video player

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am putting some HTML5 videos in a MVC3 site. The HTML5 works fine but for some reason the Flash doesn’t respond in IE, it won't even display an image.

Here is my code:

```
<video width="530px" height="445px" id="player1" poster="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/races/circuits/" + Model.Race.shortCode + ".png")" controls="controls" preload="none">
<source src="@Url.Content("~/Content/video/races/" + Model.Race.shortCode + ".mp4")" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="@Url.Content("~/Content/video/races/" + Model.Race.shortCode + ".webm")" type="video/webm" />
<object width="530" height="445" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="@Url.Content("~/Content/flash/flashmediaelement.swf")">
    <param name="movie" value="@Url.Content("~/Content/flash/flashmediaelement.swf")" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=@Url.Content("~/Content/video/races/" + Model.Race.shortCode + ".mp4")" />
    <!-- Image as a last resort -->
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/races/circuits/" + Model.Race.shortCode + ".png")" width="530px" height="445px"/>
</object>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (player, node) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});
</script>
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `data=` field, but I know that the mediaelement player really prefers direct links. Mine wasn't displaying when I tried relative links. This doesn't seem to cause problems for everyone, but it's worth a go.